# Is it possible to create index on view columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

When I am creating an index on a view, it shows the following error:

> ORA-01702: a view is not appropriate here

```
create view xx_emp for select * from emp;
```

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: create view xx_emp for select * from emp;

Answer (score 15):

You cannot create an index over a view, which is just a query.

You *can*, instead, create an index over a [**materialized** view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm). A materialized view is a table which is created by evaluating a view, so that you can create an index over it. Keep in mind, however, that a materialized view is not updated for each modification of the base table(s) over which it is defined, so you should `REFRESH` it when it must be recalculated.

Answer (score 5):

Define the index on the TABLE column (e.g. on EMP.EMP_ID)

```
create index emp_idx on emp (emp_id);
```

and use it while querying the view

```
select * from xx_emp where emp_id = 1;
```

This will not work for complex views, but for your simple case the index will be (in most cases) used to access the data.

Comment: what if our view column is generated from concating two columns in base table?

Comment: Please @Sobhan provide details in extra question. In some cases you can youe *function based index*

Answer (score -1):

You can use `INDEXED VIEW` an other keyword `SHEMABINDING` on MSSQL.
for more:
https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/03/24/what-is-indexed-view-in-sql-server-and-how-to-create-an-indexed-view/

Comment: This question is tagged [oracle]...  with an Oracle error message number.

Comment: sorry I researched for mssql then I confused I think. :(